# Boost Phoenix can no longer assign qi::_1 to variable after porting Boost 1.56 to 1.71

Tags: c++, boost, apache-phoenix, qi

I have some C++ code that uses Boost Qi and Phoenix to parse command line parameters.
The following code worked fine with Boost 1.56.

```
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
using boost::spirit::repository::distinct;

int type;
unsigned pause, siteID;
bool testMode, log;
std::string filePath;

auto fileName = qi::lexeme[+qi::char_("0-9a-zA-Z_/.:")];
auto grammar = boost::proto::deep_copy(
    distinct(qi::alpha)["/pause="][phx::ref(type) = 0] >> qi::uint_[phx::ref(pause) = qi::_1] |
    distinct(qi::alpha)["/id="][phx::ref(type) = 1] >> qi::uint_[phx::ref(siteID) = qi::_1] |
    distinct(qi::alpha)["/testmode="][phx::ref(type) = 2] >> qi::uint_[phx::ref(testMode) = (qi::_1 != FALSE)] |
    distinct(qi::alpha)["/log="][phx::ref(type) = 3] >> qi::uint_[phx::ref(log) = (qi::_1 != FALSE)] |
    distinct(qi::alpha)["/ini="][phx::ref(type) = 4] >> fileName[phx::ref(filePath) = qi::_1]
);
```

Recently I moved to Boost 1.71, but now I get the following compile time errors, all from boost.1.71.0.0\lib\native\include\boost\proto\transform\default.hpp, line 154:

```
Error C2955 'boost::type': use of class template requires template argument list
Error C2955 'boost::mpl::if_c': use of class template requires template argument list
Error C2679 binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'T' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
Error C2672 'boost::proto::detail::check_reference': no matching overloaded function
Error C2238 unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
Error C2062 type 'unknown-type' unexpected
Error C2039 'type': is not a member of 'boost::proto::detail::default_assign<Grammar>::impl<Expr     &,State,Data>::nested_and_hidden_nested_result_type'
Error C2039 'type': is not a member of 'boost::proto::detail::default_assign<Grammar>::impl<Expr &,State,Data>::nested_result_type'
```

I've worked out the issue is the code *fileName[phx::ref(filePath) = qi::_1]*.
phx::ref can no longer assign the value of qi::_1 when _1 is the result of a sub-expression.

```
qi::uint_[phx::ref(pause) = qi::_1] \\ This is fine
fileName[phx::ref(filePath) = "test"] \\ This is fine
fileName[phx::ref(filePath) = qi::_1] \\ Compile error
```

How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Can you try setting the type of `filePath` to `std::vector<char>` and then check whether it compiles?

Comment: Thanks @llonesmiz. Yes that works, then I can use std::string(filePath.begin(), filePath.end()) to get the string.Is there a more elegant way to do this conversion within the grammar?

Comment: I think [this](https://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/as.html) might be useful for the definition of `filePath`.

Comment: I tried qi::as_string<qi::_1>, but this also causes a compile time error.

Comment: `boost::any_cast<std::string>(qi::_1)` compiles ok though

Comment: I meant `auto fileName = qi::as_string[qi::lexeme[+qi::char_("0-9a-zA-Z_/.:")]];`.